# Multi-series line chart with missing values using D3 charts

Tags: d3.js

I’m plotting multi-series line chart using `D3` charts.

My data for all the series are not consistent. There are some missing values in each series.

My problem is that when I try to render graph using my data which has missing values, the graph is not created.

Please suggest me the way to handle missing data in series.

The following is my sample data in tabular and JSON format:

[image: Sample Data]

**JSON:**

```
[{
                "date": "2016-10-21 09:40",
                "param1": 5.0,
                "param2": 12.0
}, {
                "date": "2016-10-21 10:58",
                "param1": null, 
                "param2": 3.0
}, {
                "date": "2016-11-01 14:06",
                "param1": 4.0,
                "param2": 3.0
}, {
                "date": "2016-11-02 13:22",
                "param1": 1.0,
                "param2": 3.0
}, {
                "date": "2016-11-04 15:06",
                "param1": 6.0,
                "param2": 2.0
}, {
                "date": "2016-11-07 11:59",
                "param1": 1.0,
                "param2": null
}, {
                "date": "2016-11-09 13:23",
                "param1": 11.0,
                "param2": 3.0
}, {
                "date": "2016-11-10 15:08",
                "param1": 2.0,
                "param2": 1.0
}]
```

The following is the error:

[image: error snapshop]

Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide an answer without seeing any code, but you probably need a `line.defined` here: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined

According to the API:

> The defined accessor can be used to define where the line is defined and undefined, which is typically useful in conjunction with missing data.

This, if you have `null` or `undefined` in your data, put this in your line generator:

```
line.defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d[1]); });
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo,
Thanks for an early reply.
We have not used "line.defined" in our code. We have taken code from following link:
http://bl.ocks.org/Matthew-Weber/5645518

Comment: So, put that in the line generator (`var line`)